# how to append the values to the matching keys in a dictionary - python

Tags: python

I am trying to append only the values for the matching keys in a dictionary.
Below are the requirements.

```
dict1 = {A: 2, B: 4, C:7}
dict2 = {A: 1, B: 6, C:2}
dict3 = {A: 6, B: 5, C:9}
dict4 = {A: 3, B: 8, C:0}
```

> Table:
>
> A B C
>
> 2 4 7
>
> 1 6 2
>
> 6 5 9
>
> 3 8 0

Can anyone please help me with the python code for the same.
I need to create a final dictionary with `dict_final={A:[2,1,6,3], B:[4,6,5,8], C:[7,2,9,0]}`